# Finding the number of instances of a variances using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a stock synch using SQL. I am trying to query a table that holds the results from comparing product quantities data across multiple tables. I am trying to display the data for the products which have had a misalignment of greater than 0 for 7 days or more
This is the query I wrote to try to get this result

```
 select  Sap_code, Product_description, Location, Total_difference
 from  Misalignment
 where Total_difference > 0  and
 count(Total_difference) > 7
 group by Sap_code, Product_description, Location, Total_difference
```

I am getting the following error message when I run this query:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

I have included an image of the table I am querying as a point of reference

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: The error is also telling you where it needs to go: *"contained in a HAVING clause"*

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Still new to SQL so apologies if I'm not keyed in to all the error messages ...

Comment: @Larnu, I tried including the having clause and it still didn't work.

Comment: Show that attempt in your question too then, @Nitamashu . `HAVING` is exactly what you need.

Comment: The having clause did end up working. I just had it in the wrong position in my code. The answer provided by @Coskun Ozogul worked perfectly. Still very new to this so I definitely still have a lot to learn. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Does this query give what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(Total_difference) AS DiffCount, Sap_code, Product_description
    , Location, Total_difference
FROM Misalignment      
WHERE Total_difference > 0 
GROUP BY Sap_code, Product_description, Location
HAVING COUNT(Total_difference) > 7
```

Comment: Ok, you can check the answer if it is ok for you.